# Copy data range from Excel to PPT using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm using MS Excel for Mac V15.32 on macOS Sierra V10.12.3.

I'm trying to apply a practice example of VBA code to move data from Excel to PPT. It's breaking about halfway through on the following line:
PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select

The error message is "Run-time error '424': Object required".

I tried using a snippet of code from an answer to a similar question ([Copy Charts from Excel to PPT using VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518575/copy-charts-from-excel-to-ppt-using-vba-macro)), but that just crashed both applications. That code is commented out in Step 5. Code below and file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7maeqlkiciyxhwy/CopyDataToPPT.xlsm?dl=0.

Thanks for your help,
David

--
    `' http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/sending-
    excel-data-to-a-powerpoint-presentation/

```
Sub CopyRangeToPresentation()

'Step 1: Declare your variables
Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim SlideTitle As String

'Step 2: Open PowerPoint and create new presentation
Set PP = New PowerPoint.Application
Set PPPres = PP.Presentations.Add
PP.Visible = True

'Step 3: Add new slide as slide 1 and set focus to it
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPSlide.Select

'Step 4: Copy the range as a picture
Sheets("Slide Data").Range("A1:J28").CopyPicture _
Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

'Step 5: Paste the picture and adjust its position
PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
'PPPres.Slides(PPPres.Slides.Count).Shapes.Paste
PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True

'Step 6: Add the title to the slide
SlideTitle = "My First PowerPoint Slide"
PPSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

'Step 7: Memory Cleanup
PP.Activate
Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PP = Nothing

End Sub
```

--

Comment: what line are you getting your error ?

Comment: line 13 - PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select